# Horizontally slide out content with JQuery on click, click again to close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to quite find what I need. Without trying too hard to explain it, I basically need the "Connect" social media bar in the top right of this website - http://www.cmssquirrel.com/web_works/

I won't be using it for that purpose exactly, but it works exactly like I need my function to do. Everything I found seems to be a vertical menu style thing. I need to horizontally expand content on click and hide it again on click once more. Not quite sure where to begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's more of a starting point than a polished solution, but it should get you going in the right direction.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/QHEjn/20/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="open" href="#">open</a>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="slide">
            <a href="#">One</a>
            <a href="#">a</a>
            <a href="#">uaoeua</a>
            <a href="#">aoeue</a>
            <a href="#">aaoeeo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var w = 0;

$('.slide').children().each(function() {
    w += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('.outer').width(w+5);
$('.wrap').width(w);
$('.slide').css('left', w);

$('.open').toggle(function() {
    $('.slide').stop().animate({
        left: 0
    });
    $(this).html('close');
}, function() {
    $('.slide').stop().animate({
        left: w
    });
    $(this).html('open');
});
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}
.outer {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
    border-radius: 19px 19px 19px 19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
}
a {
    color: gray;
    line-height: 35px;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
}
.slide a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.slide > :first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.slide > :last-child {
    padding-right: 45px;
}
.open {
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 19px 19px 19px 19px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need! Is there a way I can get this to start closed though? 
Other than that, thanks a ton! this is the starting point I needed :)

Comment: @alpaca lips nao : But I have implemeted this in one single html, it is not working. I have added link to the <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and added $(document).ready(function()  at the top of the javaScript function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/5wYkL/11/ - Here's the same with some modifications to look like the example site I posted up above. It's FAR from clean since it's not what I need in the end, but I think it's pretty slick :)

Comment: @Amit Yadav: Error console showed illegal chars. Not sure how they ended up in the document? Anyway, here is a working version for you: http://pastebin.com/CSxbybAe

Answer (score 1):

You can extend jQuery's animation functionality to achieve this.

See a demo of this at:

http://dock.ronggur.com/tutorial/jquery%20tutorial%20-%20horizontal%20animated%20menu/

which is outlined at:

http://sandbox.ronggur.com/2009/01/25/jquery-tutorial-horizontal-animated-menu/

Essentially, you could just substitute the hover event in that demo, and use a click event.